# maxlength for AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-maxlength

I am trying to implement a maxlength functionality for a text input field.

However, whenever I go over the maxlength of 30, a message never appears saying that it's too long.

What am I doing wrong where I can implement this properly.

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">JV Number:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" ng-maxlength="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter JV Number" id="txtJVNumber" name="txtJVNumber" ng-model="formCtrl.AddCheckDeposit.JVNumber" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

### EDIT #1

I changed the field to the following after reading the documentation, but am still not receiving any warning.

Could you possibly let me know what the correct syntax should be?

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" ng-maxlength="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter JV Number" id="txtJVNumber" name="txtJVNumber" ng-model="formCtrl.AddCheckDeposit.JVNumber" />
                                <p class="help-block" ng-show="warrantyForm.txtJVNumber.$error.maxlength">Max characters of 30 exceeded</p>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error won't show up from itself.
You have to add an html element to show the error

By using ngMessages, which is a directive that is designed to show and hide messages based on the state of a key/value object that it listens on. The directive itself complements error message reporting with the ngModel $error object (which stores a key/value state of validation errors) refer to [angularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages).

for example:

```
<div ng-messages="formName.txtJVNumber.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
</div>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4v3ab63/3/) according to your jsFiddle

Comment: Dvir, thanks for your input.... If you take a look at my Edit #1, I'm still not coming out with the maxlength message. Any input as to how I can format this correctly to produce the desire result?

Comment: Dvir, here is my jsFiddle. I can't figure out whey the validation is not working. If it exceeds 30 characters, the message is supposed to show up, but doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/s4v3ab63/

Comment: You have errors on your jsFiddle so I updated it to some clean code, and you also omitted the `form` element.
I hope those errors don't appear in your real code. see the link on my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks Dvir.